# How can i show django-filter results in another view, assuming i have a search box in my home page and a results page to display the results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have been using `django-filters` in many of my projects where the search form is on the same page as the list of results and that works just fine, but now im faced by a scenario where i have a search box in my home page and a results page somewhere else, how can i pass the filtered results to the view of my results page?

Comment: change your form `action` to your desired page url path

Answer (score 0):

You could go a couple of different ways.

One idea is to just render a different template if there is search data present in the request.

Seeing as you didn't post any of your own code, we don't know how you have things named or set-up so here is a quick sketch of the kind of thing I mean.

```
class SomeView(View):
    template_name = 'some_view.html'
    results_template_name = 'some_view_results.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.GET.get('q'):
            return render(request, self.template_name)
        results = SearchFilter(request.GET)
        context = {'results': results}
        return render(request, self.results_template_name, context)
```

This would be one of the simplest solutions. You could even get away with using one template and just conditionally dispatch some rendering over whether or not `results` is in the context.

Another would be to do a full `redirect` and pass along whatever data you need as `kwargs` to whatever view you are calling. But that is kind of messy and unnecessary.

The best solution is to wire up a new `ResultsView` endpoint, move the filtering to that view, and put a reference that URL into the form node on the template. Which would require something like this.

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url search %}">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Assuming that you have named `ResultsView` as `search` in your URL config.